# My src.rpm does not contain the source files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm working on a CentOS 4.1 machine, and I'm using rpm-build for creating an rpm that pastes a some binaries in a required location. 
My .spec is:

```
Summary: FOO1 Data
Name: foo
Version: 1.0
Release: 1
License: GNU
Group: FOO1
URL: www.foo1data.com
Source0: foo.src 
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-buildroot

%description

%define installdir $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/foo1/foo1-dummy

%prep
cd /usr/src/redhat/BUILD
rm -rf foo.src 
cp -rp /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES/foo.src /usr/src/redhat/BUILD
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
  exit $? 
fi
cd foo.src 
cd /usr/src/redhat/BUILD/foo.src
chown -R root.root .
chmod -R a+rX,g-w,o-w .

%build

cd foo.src/main/
./build_all
cd -

%install
[ "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" != "/" ] && rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

mkdir -p %{installdir}/agg
install foo.src/main/agg/server/aggd %{installdir}/agg/aggd
install foo.src/main/tools/conmsgtest %{installdir}/agg/conmsgtest
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin
ln -f -s /foo1/foo1-dummy/agg/conmsgtest $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/conmsgtest

%clean 
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/foo1/foo1-dummy/agg/aggd
/foo1/foo1-dummy/agg/conmsgtest
/usr/local/bin/conmsgtest
```

My foo-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm file performs as expected. However, my foo-1.0-1.src.rpm file, when I run the command

> rpm -ivh foo-1.0-1.src.rpm

the foo.src directory that gets added in the /usr/src/redhat/SOURCES directory is empty. Nevertheless, the correct spec file does get added to the SPECS directory.

I'm a total noob w.r.t rpmbuild, so can anyone please tell me what I need to do so that my src rpm contains the sources?

Also, the command

> rpm --rebuild foo-1.0-1.src.rpm

returns "--rebuild: unknown option", is there a equivalent option I can use in CentOS?

Edit: 
Thanks to Satya, I tried the command

> rpmbuild --rebuild foo-1.0-1.src.rpm

I get the error

```
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.19105: line 27: cd: foo.src/main/: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.19105 (%build)
```

Comment: have you trying taking a look at http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-rpm-using.html

Comment: @Satya Thank you for your link, however I'm unable to find what is wrong with my spec file in the link provided. Also, the --rebuild option is supposed to be valid according to http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM but I don't see it in the manual.

Comment: isn't the command rpmbuild --rebuild instead of rpm --rebuild ?

Comment: @Satya It is! Thanks. So, now because of the absence of the source files, I get the error "No such file or directory" for "foo.src/main"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem, sort of. It seems that the source *has* to be a **tarball**, not a directory (like I have done in the spec file posted in the question).

So, compressing the foo.src directory to foo.tar.gz, and uncompromising it to /usr/src/redhat/BUILD directory during the %prep phase seems to work out for me. Now, the .src.rpm file found in the SRPMS directory pastes the foo.tar.gz file in the SOURCES directory as expected when run. 
(Although, this still doesn't explain why directories aren't accepted....)

Comment: That's just the way it is... a `src` RPM bundles a `spec` file, one or more archives, and zero or more patches.